# Can I config tortoisehg to show red icon when file status not empty

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

For example, I add new file forget about hg add, the folder is green but file status show one file with question mark.

Comment: Can you please reword your question, or add some more information. You added a new file to a repo, it is greeen, and you want it to be red?

Comment: Yes. I add file to the repository folder and want it to be red after that without "hg add".

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, no. Maybe some day we can have an unversioned icon for the new files: [is there some reason to not use ignored and unknown overlay icons?](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.mercurial.tortoisehg.user/2380)